# Почему никогда не срабатывает else?

Tags: scss

У меня есть функция которая проверяет соотношение сторон экрана. Если соотношение сторон экрана меньше или равно 7/4, то функция возвращает значение в единицах vh. Если соотношение сторон экрана больше 7/4, то функция возвращает значение в единицах vw. Но у меня на всех разрешениях у класса .example - font-size выводит значение с vh , в else оно не заходит , как это исправить ?

```css
@function get-vh($object) {
   @if (min-aspect-ratio: 7/4) {
      $vh-sm: (1080 * 0.01) * 1px;
      @return ($object / $vh-sm) * 1vh;
   } @else {
      $vh-lg: (1920 * 0.01) * 1px;
      @return ($object / $vh-lg) * 1vw;
   }
}

.example {
   font-size: get-vh(30px);
}
```

Comment: Не очень понятно, почему вы решили, что в @if можно использовать min-aspect-ratio

Comment: Собственно, выражение `min-aspect-ratio: 7/4` скорее всего воспринимается как [Map](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps/) с ключом `"min-aspect-ratio"` и значением `1.75`, и так как этот Map является непустым, то он считается истинным и условие if выполняется. Если вы ожидали чего-то другого, то непонятно, почему вы этого ожидали

Comment: `@function get-vw($object) {
   $vh-lg: (1920 * 0.01) * 1px;
   @return ($object / $vh-lg) * 1vw;
}
@function get-vh($object) {
   $vh-sm: (1080 * 0.01) * 1px;
   @return ($object / $vh-sm) * 1vh;
}

@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 7/4) {
   .example {
      font-size: get-vh(30px);
      color: red;
   }
}

@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 7/4) {
   .example {
      font-size: get-vw(30px);
      color: blue;
   }
} `
если я сделаю так , то все работает , но я не хочу дублировать код просто с изминенной одной буквой , хотел как-то сделать через условие

Comment: Ну `@media` и `@if` это таки абсолютно разные вещи

Answer (score 0):

в твоем коде проверяется не текущие соотношение, а минимальное.
если использовать media queries то может быть ошибка исправится
вот возможное решение:

```
@function get-font-size($object) {
  @if (min-width: 1200px) {
    @return ($object / 1920 * 100) + vw; 
  } @else {
    @return ($object / 1080 * 100) + vh;
  }
}

.example {
  @media (min-aspect-ratio: 7/4) {
    font-size: get-font-size(30px);
  }

  @media (max-aspect-ratio: 7/4) {
    font-size: get-font-size(30px);
  }
}
```

Comment: Этот код выдаёт два абсолютно одинаковых стиля

Comment: @dan_bat В вашем примере вы используете два раз font-size с разными media , а я хотел сделать так , чтобы я посылал в функцию значение оно проверяло какое сейчас соотношение сторон , при помощи min-aspect-ratio: 7/4 и max-aspect-ratio: 7/4 и уже выставляло ему или vh или vw, просто у меня тут сейчас один класс объявлен , это не так страшно когда два раза указан font-size, просто когда кода будет больше , будет не сильно приятно

Answer (score 0):

```
@function get-font-size($object) {

  @if (min-width: 1200px) {
    @return ($object / 1920 * 100) + vw;
  } @else {
    @return ($object / 1080 * 100) + vh; 
  }

  @if (min-aspect-ratio: 7/4) {
    @return ($object / 1080 * 100) + vh;
  } @else {
    @return ($object / 1920 * 100) + vw;
  }

}

.example {
  font-size: get-font-size(30px); 
}
```

Теперь в самой функции мы проверяем соотношение сторон.

Comment: При любом разрешении у меня всегда font-size: 1.56vw

Comment: А этот код мало того что выводит один-единственный стиль, так он ещё и сломанный

Comment: Да и в нём просто чушь написана. Если вы не знаете SCSS и как он работает, то не надо пытаться угадать